# I been patiently waiting ! Where is have?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, auxiliary-verbs

Explain me please, why there is no auxiliary verb "have" in this sentence :

> I been patiently waiting

?

Comment: It's an ungrammatical / dialectal reduced version of *I'**ve** been waiting*. Don't copy it.

Comment: You can find this version (as Perfect Progressive) in African-American Vernacular English (sometimes called 'ebonics'): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English

Answer (score 3):

This question was answered in the comments. IMHO, the following are indeed correct:

"It's an ungrammatical / dialectal reduced version of I've been waiting. Don't copy it." – FumbleFingers

"You can find this version (as Perfect Progressive) in African-American Vernacular English (sometimes called 'ebonics'): en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English" – Alex_ander